# Python Kivy. Как сделать так, чтобы раскрывающийся список не перекрывал кнопки снизу, а сдвигал их?

Tags: python, kivy

У меня такая проблема: есть список кнопок с выпадающими списками(идут они сверху вниз), но при нажатии на кнопку, выпадающий список перекрывает кнопки снизу, а не сдвигает их ниже. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу реализовать этот сдвиг?

Answer (score 0):

Если список типа [kivy.uix.dropdown](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html), то кнопки внутри этого списка создаются в момент его открытия на отдельном layout-е, который именно рисуется поверх виджетов на нижнем слое.
Если нужно, чтобы список кнопок сдвинул всё, что находится дальше, то я бы не использовал *dropdown*, а поместил список самодельных кнопок в отдельный **BoxLayout**, например:

```
names = ['Кнопка первая', 'Кнопка вторая', 'Кнопка третья']
buttons = []

for n in names:
    buttons.append(Button(text = n)

lay = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')

for b in buttons:
    lay.add_widget(b)
```

Чтобы скрыть список, нужно будет освободить Layout от виджетов с помощью:

```
lay.clear_widgets()
```

А сам BoxLayout с кнопками добавить в другой Layout рядом с кнопкой, открывающей/закрывающей список по функции *on_release*.